# Grouping similar key values to an array in N1Ql couchbase query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
[
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "product": "iPhone 12"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "product": "iPhone 11"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "product": "Note 10"
    },
    {
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "product": "Note20"
    }
]
```

I have a data set like the above in my bucket.

How can I query (like below) grouping the products from the same brand, with the count?

```
[
    {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "products": [{
            "product": "iPhone 12"
        }, {
            "product": "iPhone 11"
        }],
        "count_of_products": 2
    },
    {
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "products": [{
            "product": "Note10"
        }, {
            "product": "Note20"
        }],
        "count_of_products": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/select-syntax.html#group-by-clause) and [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-agg)

```
SELECT brand, ARRAY_AGG({product}) AS products, COUNT(1) AS count_of_products
FROM mybucket
WHERE .....
GROUP BY brand;
```